# Can we use **In which** or/and **By which** at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, commas, expression-choice

I am wondering if it is accepted to use **In which** or/and **By which** or any other similar phrase at the beginning of the sentence and then use a comma.
For example:

*""Thus, only the hardware-based solutions have been taken into consideration. **In which**, the revolutionary hardware technologies’ advances are being exploited"*

I tried to find something and I found it used without any comma at all in the middle of a sentence like [this](http://answers.ask.com/reference/dictionaries/how_to_use_in_which) or after a comma like [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=403323).

Comment: As it appears, the context is far from fictional literature, and closer home to serious technical writing. *Thus,* one must use straightforward sentences. *In which,* the structure lends itself to the minimum of backward or forward references, within or outside the sentence itself. (If this is very clear, my point is lost though.) :)  **ExecSum**: No.

Answer (score 1):

The word *which* introduces [*a restrictive relative clause*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/clauses#restrictive_relative_clause) (also known as a defining relative clause). This clause gives essential information about a noun **that comes before it**: without this clause the sentence wouldn’t make much sense. (A restrictive relative clause can be introduced by that, which, whose, who, or whom.)  As such, to use it in the beginning of a sentence would not make much sense.

I have seen this use, however, in older books as chapter titles:

> In Which (so and so) Learns of his Unfortunate Circumstances

It sounds quaint and pleasant there, but hasn't much place in modern writing.

Comment: And in chapter titles, it's not a sentence.